# php takes 1+ minute to send mail with sendmail & maildev

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

Maildev is running with

```
maildev -s 25
```

PHP is setup with

```
[mail function]
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
smtp_port = 25
```

When I try to send mail (with PHPMailer), I see that sendmail is running:

```
0784 www-data   20   0  4508   748   672 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 sh -c /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  -oi -fmailer-daemon@host.com
```

And after about ~2mn, that process ends and mails are sent to Maildev.

I don't understand why mails are not directly sent to Maildev...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found it!

In my /var/logs/mail.log I had this error log:

```
My unqualified host name (hugo) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

Then 1 minute later :

```
Unable to qualify my own domain name (hugo) -- using short name
```

I fixed this error with https://askubuntu.com/a/436270/510570, by:

Setting a good FQDN in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 hugo.example.com hugo
```

And applying it:

```
sudo hostname hugo.example.com
```